# SQL Query to get all the data from tables when there is no parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am trying to get the whole data when there are no filters selected. I have made an array that contains the selections. In case there are no selections then there will be just `''` , i.e. no characters but not null.

```
SELECT * FROM Skills WHERE person IN ('Technology', 'Drilling');
```

For example - In this query it will return all required - filtered data. So my array contains `Technology` and `Drilling`. In case there is nothing selected by the user as a filter then the query would look like:

```
SELECT * FROM Skills WHERE person IN ('');
```

In this case the table is returning nothing in SQL Server. I want it to return everything from the table without any filters.

I would really like to get some help here and maybe some resources that might help me achieve the required thing.

The array is being filled in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

It seems really strange to have a column called `person` compared to values like "Drilling".  But you would do something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM Skills
WHERE person IN (<whatever>) OR <whatever> = '';
```

Often `NULL` is used to mean everything, so that would be:

```
WHERE person IN (<whatever>) OR <whatever> IS NULL;
```

And "whatever" might be a delimited string, so this might look like:

```
WHERE person IN (SELECT s.value FROM string_split(@params) s) OR
      @params IS NULL;
```

Comment: But my params will be = " ' ' ". Single quote in double quotes. Will this work in that case too? Because params will not be null. I am actually a little confused.

Comment: @SayantoRoy . . . That is the first answer.  I'm just suggesting `NULL` because it is often used for this purpose.